# Display how many followers and following

Tags: users

I am using user_relationship module.

I would like to display on user profiles how many followers do they have and how many do they follow...

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: I have just run into this same problem, but I was using the Flags module. I have made a blog post about it, because it is a tricky problem. http://www.leesome.com/blog/2013/02/18/creating-following-and-followers-tabs-with-flags-in-drupal-7/